# mongodb results with array to individual results map

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework

I have an aggregate query that is doing exactly what I want up to this point, but I am stuck transforming the data at the last step. I have the following:

```
{
    "name": "a",
    "tasks": [ { .. }, { .. }]
},
{
    "name": "b",
    "tasks": [ { .. }, { .. }]
}
```

all I need to do is map each entry in `tasks` to a separate result. Sounds incredibly simple to me.

The expected output should be

```
{ "name": "a", "task": { .. } },
{ "name": "a", "task": { .. } },
{ "name": "b", "task": { .. } },
{ "name": "b", "task": { .. } }
```

I tried using `{ $unwind: '$tasks' }` in hopes that I could get separate entries, but it only seems to expand the first result. I only get the tasks from `a`.

I also tried `$map` but had similar problems.

If necessary, there is an `_id` inside of each `task` that could be used for uniqueness. Thats really what I'm trying to accomplish, a map of key-value pairs such as

```
{ "_id": "idFromTheTask", "name": "a" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) is the right way unless your `tasks` array is empty. In that case it will remove such document. To prevent that you can use `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays`, try:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: {
            path: "$tasks",
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }
    }
])
```

An example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JXybb74zZFY)

Comment: odd. I am getting 20 results, but there are 40 total tasks among 5 original results. Still not sure why

Comment: Actually, the first entry alone has 21 tasks, and using `$unwind` is still only giving me 20 in robo 3t

Comment: I think `20` is the default size of the cursor, maybe you can run .toArray on it or just add `{ limit: 100 }` to control the number of returned documents

Comment: you are right, adding `toArray()` in robo 3t solved the issue